# Is it possible to enable/disable a custom deserializer depending on the API endpoint being called?

Tags: json, jackson, retrofit2

I'm accessing a JSON API which has 2 kinds of endpoints:

- the first kind returns a list of objects of the same type (Symptom, ChronicDisease...)
- the second kind (a search function) returns a mixed list of objects of different types (those types are the same than can be returned by the first kind of API)

In the second case, each item of the list has a type field telling which is the type of the object. This field doesn't exist in the first case.

I would like to use the default deserializer for the first kind of API and a custom deserializer for the second kind of API. Is it possible?

If I only use the default deserializer, API calls of the first kind will work but I'm unable to perform a search.

If I enable the following deserializer, the search will work but the deserializer is also used when using the first kind of API and it fails because the type field is missing.

Custom deserializer I'd like to use:

```
class SearchableItemDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<SearchableItem>() {

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): SearchableItem {
        val root : JsonNode = p.readValueAsTree()
        val type : String = root.get("type").asText()
        when(type){
            "symptom" -> {
                return ObjectMapper().readValue(root.asText(), Symptom::class.java)
        }
            "symptom_group" -> {
                return ObjectMapper().readValue(root.asText(), SymptomGroup::class.java)
            }
            "diagnosis" -> {
                return ObjectMapper().readValue(root.asText(), Diagnose::class.java)
            }
            "chronic_disease" -> {
                return ObjectMapper().readValue(root.asText(), ChronicDisease::class.java)
            }
        }
        throw Exception("Unable to deserialize type $type")
    }
}
```

Interface common to Symptom, SymptomGroup, Diagnose and ChronicDisease:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SearchableItemDeserializer::class)
interface SearchableItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You can extent [Converter.Factory](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Converter.Factory.html) to create you custom converter. Probably most dumb and direct way would be to add check for specific retrofit annotation inside "requestBodyConverter" or "responseBodyConverter" methods.

Something like:

```
class CustomConverter : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type,
                                       annotations: Array<Annotation>,
                                       retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        return responseConverter(*annotations)
                .responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit)
    }

    private fun responseConverter(vararg methodAnnotations: Annotation): Converter.Factory {
        return when {
            endpoint1(*methodAnnotations) -> converter1
            endpoint2(*methodAnnotations) -> converter2
            else -> defaultConverter
        }
    }

    override fun requestBodyConverter(type: Type,
                                      parameterAnnotations: Array<Annotation>,
                                      methodAnnotations: Array<Annotation>,
                                      retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<*, RequestBody>? {
   //same approach here
    }

fun endpoint1(vararg annotations: Annotation): Boolean {
   //condition check here
}

fun endpoint2(vararg annotations: Annotation): Boolean {
   //and here (if needed)
}
```

Just add your endpoints 1/2 implementation (probably just compare @Get() contents with certain pattern or something like that) and repeat same instruction for requestConverter.

When ready, just add it to retrofit:

```
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(CustomConverter())
                .build()
```